# Pulling a subset of elements from a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns a set of values from a `Dictionary`.
I don't currently want to allow it to throw `KeyNotFoundException`, so I'm filtering the keys out before I try to select the values.

I have a feeling this can be done in a more straightforward fashion, but I'm not sure where to go with it.

```
// this.resources is a Dictionary<string, Resource>

public IEnumerable<Resource> GetResources(IEnumerable<string> resourceNames)
{
    HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>(resourceNames);

    hs.IntersectWith(this.resources.Keys);

    List<Resource> resources = new List<Resource>();

    foreach(string resourceName in hs)
    {
        resources.Add(this.resources[resourceName]);
    }

    return resources;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would write it the obvious straight-forward LINQ way, which gives you good readability as well as lazy evaluation:

```
public IEnumerable<Resource> GetResources(IEnumerable<string> resourceNames)
{
    return resourceNames
        .Where(name => resources.ContainsKey(name))
        .Select(name => resources[name]);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: you probably meant `yield return resourceNames..`